# Apache PdfBox Rotate Crop Box Only Not Text

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to go from text to pdf but have only one of the pages rotated 90 degress. Main reason is that some of my text documents are a bit too large and need to be in landscape to look normal. I have tried a few things but it seems like everything rotates the text too. Is there an easy way to rotate the pdf to landscape but keep the text the same rotation?

```
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
        Map<String, Documents> documents = getDocuments(user, documentReports);

        try (PDDocument documentToPrint = new PDDocument()){
            for(Document doc : documentReports){
                TextToPDF textToPDF = new TextToPDF();
                textToPDF.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER);
                textToPDF.setFontSize(8);

                Document documentReport = documents.get(doc.getId());
                try(PDDocument pdDocument = textToPDF.createPDFFromText(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(documentReport.getReportText().getBytes())))) {
                    pdfMergerUtility.appendDocument(documentToPrint, pdDocument);
                }
            }
            pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
            LocalDateTime localUtcTime = Java8TimeUtil.getCurrentUtcTime();
            documentToPrint.getDocumentInformation().setTitle(localUtcTime.toString());
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + localUtcTime + ".pdf");
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            documentToPrint.save(outputStream);
        }
```

Comment: You mean like relayouting the document and reflowing the text to match the different page size?

Comment: @mkl Yes, but not have the text rotate.

Comment: Reflowing PDF content is highly non-trivial if the PDF in question is not tagged.

Comment: @mkl What do you mean if it is not tagged? The pdf is initially in text format. So I am converting it from text to pdf. So can I first set the orientation when creating the pdf from text? Each text file is first converted to pdf then merged onto a single pdf. So anytime between those steps if I can rotate that document before I merge it onto the final pdf.

Comment: *Tagged PDFs* internally contain extra information to help programs recognize the semantic structures of the PDF content.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks for the clerification. I answered my own question but it is very specific to me creating a pdf from text. Might not help someone who is wanting to change orientation of the pdf and does not have the textToPdf like i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this might not work for everyone but I figured it out for my specific requirement. TextToPDF has a method called setLandscape before creating the pdf from text. textToPDF.setLandscape(true);